# System.drawing.common PlatformNotSUpportedException when targeting netstandard2.0 but it is supposed to work on Windows?

Tags: .net, drawing, platform

My project target is netstandard2.0-windows. My platform is windows 11.  All doc indicates that this should work on windows but I get

Unhandled Exception: System.PlatformNotSupportedException: System.Drawing.Common is not supported on this platform.

I'm also using the Microsoft.Windows.Compatibility package.

suggestions?

Comment: Hmm, it works if I target net6.0.  That's interesting, but it doesn't help me.

Comment: I also notice that the nuget folder structure does not contain a "netstandard2.0" folder under "lib".  Other packages that claim a netstandard2.0 target do have this folder.  I don't know the significance of this difference.

Comment: "netstandard2.0-windows" is not a thing that exists. [Target frameworks in SDK-style projects](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/frameworks). OS-specific target frameworks are only available on .NET 5+

Comment: @SpaceBeeGaming, thanks for that.  Curiously, it was accepted by VS, built, and populated a netstandard-windows output folder.  But no matter, I've also tested with tfm "netstandard2.0" with the same results.

Comment: I'm coming to the conclusion that it's simply a fact that system.drawing.common in .netstandard2.0 is only supported when the runtime is .net (core/5+).  Not mentioned anywhere that I can find, but simple tests prove this out.